# Rails custom e-mail validator | Blacklist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, model, blacklist

**Situation:**

I got a *user* model, which needs to be validated by a list of blacklisted e-mail addresses. The blacklisted e-mail addresses are located in an extra model called *blacklist*

## models/user.rb:

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
            validate :email_is_not_blacklisted

            def email_is_not_blacklisted
                    @blacklist = Blacklist.where(:blacklist_type => "E-Mail")

                    @blacklist.each do |item|
                            errors.add(:email, 'is blacklisted') if self.email.match(item)
                    end
            end
    end
```

## models/blacklist.rb

```
    class Blacklist < ActiveRecord::Base
            attr_accessible :name, :blacklist_type

            #some validation code for blacklist items ...
    end
```

## Blacklist entry examples

```
    #:        name,            blacklist_type
    #1:       'demo-mail.com', 'E-Mail'
    #2:       'test123.com',   'E-Mail'
```

The blacklist model also will be used to ban specific usernames in the future!

**Problem:**

My problem is that *[at]blacklist* is always *nil*. Maybe there is something wrong with my logic? In other words: is it possible to access a model inside another model without an accosiation anyway?

Thanks for your help in advance and apologies existing language faults. I'm not a native english speaker :)

**SOLUTION!**
I missed to define which attribute of the item should be used ...

```
    errors.add(:email, 'is blacklisted') if self.email.match(item.name)
```

Sometimes my brain doesn't like the way I like ...

Comment: Hmm so basically it IS possible to access `Blacklist` from within `User`, or you would get an Exception... However, try changing `@blacklist` to `blacklist`... i think validators are called as Class Methods, not Instance Methods (and thus don't have instance vars)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will suggest you to use this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :email_is_not_blacklisted

  def email_is_not_blacklisted
    if Blacklist.find_by_blacklist_type_and_name("E-Mail",self.email)
       errors.add(:email, 'is blacklsited') 
    end
  end
end
```

this will be faster then the previous ones

Comment: Yes, I also think this will work faster, but the blacklist can contain only the domain name which is blocked. So I have to check it with a match/regex =/

Answer (score 0):

Case sensitivity. You're searching for blacklist-type = "E-Mail" and your example data is "e-mail"

Comment: Sorry for this mistake! I corrected my question to provide data consistency :) In my database the blacklist_type is the same as in my where condition.

Comment: you sure `@blacklist` is nil. You could not be getting the errors as your if condition doesn't look right.

Comment: Thanks buddy :) I missed to declare which attribute of item should be used ...

The nil error is untenable ... my debug point was one step too early -.-

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my comment, try this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :email_is_not_blacklisted

  def email_is_not_blacklisted
    Blacklist.find_all_by_blacklist_type("E-Mail").each do |item|
      errors.add(:email, 'is blacklsited') if.self.email.match(item)
    end
  end
end
```